# Tui calendar javascript working on localhost but not working host

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm building a calendar application using tui calendar.
With the changes I made in 'app-calendar.js' and 'schedules.js', I brought the calendar to the format I wanted.
It works fine on localhost. But when I upload it to the live server, the changes I made in 'app-calendar.js' and 'schedules.js' are not visible, not working as i want.

[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FZwe.png)

[host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/266U7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you use some sort of package manager to fetch the scripts on the server. Since you edit the library locally, the changes are not accessible in the original code of the library - obviously. Either you load edited script manually from a static location on your site or change the way you use this script. So your code works on top of the library rather than mixing it.

Comment: This is how I load it in default.blade.php:


`<script src="{{ asset('admin/app-assets/js/scripts/extensions/calendar/app-calendar.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('admin/app-assets/js/scripts/extensions/calendar/schedules.js')}}"></script>`